# Different types of brackets?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I would like to ask you about your preferred way of typesetting math functions with brackets and arguments, like $f(x)$ or $x(y+1)$. I think there is the possibility to get confused by this, because the first example shows a function call, and the second a multiplication. Does there exist some general style guide for something like this?

Comment: You may want to address this question to [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: For what my opinion is worth, I'd say that anyone with even just a smattering of math training would ever think that `f(x+1)` might represent the product of `f` and `x+1`.

Comment: It is like asking if `f(x)` is a function what is `x(f)`? Like what Mico is saying, it will be clear from context. There will also be situations where `x` is a function.

Comment: @Mico `(a+b+c+d+e+f)(x+1) = a(x+1) + b(x+1) + c(x+1) + d(x+1) + e(x+1) + f(x+1)` for you to contemplate:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Uncle! Uncle!! The pain is just too great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode has two invisible characters to address this issue

U+2061 FUNCTION APPLICATION  (html entity `&ApplyFunction;`)

U+2062 INVISIBLE TIMES (html entity `&InvisibleTimes;`)

So if using Unicode math fonts (say the `unicode-math` package with lualatex or xelatex) then you could use these characters before the `(` to distinguish the cases (doing the equivalent in MathML markup can lead to more accessible audio versions) However in any translation to 8 bit math fonts for classic tex these characters need to be dropped.

Even in Unicode TeX adding them does not usually add much information as in a construct like `\log(x)` the markup is already distinguishing `log` as a mathop so function application can be assumed, so it only helps in the cases as you show where the first term is a `\mathord` variable with no specified math class.

Probably related to this somewhat restricted usefulness in a TeX context `unicode-math` does not provide any tex commands to access these characters (but you could add them directly or via `^^^^2061` notation).